# Pulsed power calculation

Tags: power, loss

I want to calculate power loss across a resistive load during a 1 ms interval. The experimental setup is such that the voltage and current through the load varies the whole period of 1 ms. I have 10,000 voltage and current values within this 1 ms period. I am exploring the best way to find the power loss in this case. I have tried multiplying each instant's voltage and current (P= vi), and using trapz function in Matlab, I tried to find out the energy loss value (E=trapz(t,P)). However, I want to learn about the better ways to calculate power loss across the load over the 1 ms period.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share a graph of your P(t) values? Do you have a reason to think your result is not accurate enough?

Comment: multiplying each pair of current.voltage values and summing/integrating the power across the interval is the correct way to do it. The only 'better ways' are to take short cuts when you can definitely assume some things about the setup to avoid calculating them all, for instance constant voltage and current across the interval.

Comment: If I multiply voltage,current and timestamp at each timestamp (E=v*i*t) and sum them together over a period of 1 ms, it gives me an output of 1010. This is different from the result (0.0029) obtained from the MATLAB using trapz function. I am not sure which result is more meaningful.

Comment: 1010 whats? 0.0029 whats? What are your units?

Comment: The unit is joule

Comment: I think that all of that information and your calculation method needs to be in the question rather than buried in the comments.

Comment: @Allison_81 Do you know what the trapz() function does? If you do then you should be able to replicate it in your own computation and arrive at a very similar result. (You may either be abusing the trapz() function by providing it with information that isn't expected by the function. Or you may have an error in your code. Or there may be a constant that needs to be applied, which the trapz() is doing and you are failing to do, for example. Also, what can you tell us about the process itself that you are measuring. A priori knowledge will have a large bearing on the better method to apply.

Answer (score 2):

> If I multiply voltage,current and timestamp at each timestamp (E=vit) and sum them together over a period of 1 ms, ...

You should be using \$ E = \Sigma vi \Delta t \$ where \$ \Delta t \$ is the *sample period in seconds*, not the timestamp which will increase with each sample.